# Problems with rand

Tags: c#

I have such code:
String text has some {AVATAR}in it

```
    if (text.Contains("{AVATAR}"))
        text = Regex.Replace(text, "{AVATAR}", m => rand_avatars());
public string rand_avatars()
{
    string[] text = avatars.ToArray();
    Random rand = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
    return text[rand.Next(text.Length)];
}
```

But after replace in out I receive 2 same strings from avatars. Why?

Comment: I had similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15162048/very-weird-code-with-random-works-different-when-i-use-breakpoint

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is probably because `DateTime.Now.Millisecond` has not changed between the calls, and therefore the same seed is being used twice for the random number generator.

You should make the Random object a field and initialise it once only, then re-use it in `rand_avatars()`.

Alternatively, initialise it once as a local before doing the replace, and pass it in to `rand_avatars(Random random)` (having added Random as a parameter to `rand_avatars()`).

Comment: @IlyaIvanov No, it's `Environment.TickCount` which is used as the seed by default.

Comment: @MatthewWatson yes, thanks you, just saw after decompiling `Random`

Answer (score 5):

Use the same `Random` object and just call `Next` every time. If you create a new `Random` object for every number, you'll get similar results.

```
private Random _r = new Random();

void Foo()
{
    /// ...

    if (text.Contains("{AVATAR}"))
        text = Regex.Replace(text, "{AVATAR}", m => rand_avatars());

    /// ...
}

string rand_avatars()
{
    string[] text = avatars.ToArray();
    return text[_r.Next(text.Length)];
}
```

*Edit:* By the way, the `if` clause is unnecessary because `Regex.Replace` won't replace anything if the pattern isn't matched.